# $ionicHistory.backView() returning wrong view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

When I am using $ionicHistory.backView() it is returning the view that was before the view previous to the current view, so it is going one step back than it should be. But when I refresh the page on the view previous to the current one, where I am testing $ionicHistory.backView() it is returning null. For some reason I am not getting anything for that specific view.

This is my code:

```
.controller('RegisterController', function($scope, $state, UserService, $auth, MessageService, $ionicHistory) {
  $scope.user = UserService.get();
  $scope.validate = {};
  $scope.registerPromise = {};

console.log($ionicHistory.backView());
```

And these are the routes:

```
.state('main.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthController',
      }
    },
    authenticate: false
  })

  .state('main.login2', {
    url: '/login2',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login2.html',
        controller: 'AuthController',
      }
    },
    authenticate: false
  })

.state('register.contact', {
    url: '/contact',
    views: {
      form: {
        templateUrl: 'templates/user/register-contact.html',
      }
    }
  })
```

So, the flow is when the user is on the `main.login` page, he can either go to the `register.contact` page where he leaves the contact details, or go to the `main.login2` page where he can login or reset the password by going again to `register.contact` page where he can again send his contact details for reseting the password. That is why I need to know for my form where is the user coming from, since I am using the same form for two things, leaving the contact details for registering and reseting the password. But I am not getting the correct data from `$ionicHistory.backView()`

Comment: if you reload the view automatically u will lost the data,so try to set some kind of local or session variables and access them to meet your requirement

Comment: yes, but how to get the correct data from $ionicHistory,backView()?

Comment: $ionicHistory is held in local memory, which is lost when the page is reloaded. If you need to keep track of the users steps, then you will need to persist this data somewhere